# How to rename 80.000 files at once in Windows

Tags: windows-7, command-line

I've 80.000 files in a folder and I need to rename all them from

```
filename.jpg
```

to

```
._filename.jpg
```

in Windows environment, I guess from dos. The reason is that I've compressed these files into a tar.gz from unix and copied into windows and for some reason the filenames have changed.

Could you tell me what's the command to do it ?
thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the built in [`rename` or `ren`](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/rename.mspx?mfr=true) command:

> `ren *.jpg ._*.jpg`

Though, as with all these things, try it on a directory containing just a few files first.

Comment: I like your approach, but i have 2 issues: (1) the first letters of the filenames are replaced. In other terms, the "._" is not added at the beginning but it replaces the first 2 letters. (2) "._" actually doesn't work. If I use, for instance "__" then it works. I think the dot, "." gives some issues

Comment: @Patrick - I must admit I didn't have chance to fully test this this, and yes I think you're right about the dot causing problems.

Comment: **This is incorrect** and it's not because of the dots. `ren` can only replace text with text of the same length. For example, if you have files `file1.txt` and `file2.txt`, `ren file*.txt blah*.txt` does what you expect (you now have files `blah1.txt` and `blah2.txt`). However, if you then type `ren blah*.txt myfile*.txt` the command bombs out because it renames `blah1.txt` to `myfile.txt` (not `myfile1.txt`) and then cannot rename `blah2.txt` to `myfile.txt` because that file already exists.

Answer (score 15):

Here's a way using PowerShell:

Navigate to your folder and run this command

```
Get-ChildItem *.jpg | Rename-Item -newname {"._" + $_.Name}
```

Extra bonus short version:

```
gci *.jpg | ren -newname {"._" + $_.Name}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have 2 solutions:

1. All files are in the same folder

   - run the following from command prompt on that folder:

     ```
     for /f "delims=¯" %i in ('dir /b /on') do ren "%i" "._%i"
     ```
2. complete solution when there are files in subfolders AND when you wanna to replace the "n" first characters with a string you want :D

   - create a batch file with the following command
   - change variable parameters to what you want

     - `path`: put inside `""` the root path of your files (e.g. "C:\documents and settings\user\desktop\new folder"
     - `numfirstchars2replace`: put a number with the first characters to replace (in your case, 2)
     - `str2put`: put a string to be added as a prefix of the new filename (in your case, `._`)
   - run it in a folder different from where the files are

```
@echo off

::only to tell user what this bat are doing
echo.1.initializing...

::enable that thing to allow, for example, incremental counter in a for loop :)
echo.- EnableDelayedExpansion
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion

::variables
echo.- variables
:: - place here the absolute root path of your files
set path="put here where are the root folder of your files"
set pathbak=%cd%
set numfirstchars2replace=2
set str2put=._

::go to %path% and its driveletter
echo.- entering the path you want
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('echo.%path%') do %%~di
cd %path%

::search all subfolders and save them to a temp file
echo.- searching for subfolders
echo.%path%>%temp%\tmpvar.txt
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('dir /s /b /on /ad') do echo."%%i">>%temp%\tmpvar.txt

::execute command for root folder and all found subfolders
echo.
echo.2.executing...
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in (%temp%\tmpvar.txt) do (
  cd %%i
  echo.- in folder: %%i
  for /f "delims=¯" %%j in ('dir /b /on /a-d') do (
    set newname=%%j
    set newname=!newname:~%numfirstchars2replace%,1000!
    echo.- renaming from "%%j" to "%str2put%!newname!"...
    ren "%%j" "%str2put%!newname!"
  )
)

echo.
echo.3.exiting...
::return to %pathbak% and its driveletter
for /f "delims=¯" %%i in ('echo.%pathbak%') do %%~di
cd %pathbak%

@echo on
```

Comment: fully tested :) it solves your problem, including with some specs you give in @ChrisF comment. note: in "delims=¯", if "¯" is used in a filename, change "¯" with another character you know that is not used in the filenames

Comment: voted up because of your incredibly long script to just do a loop and rename sth. :)

Comment: well, justly, I could make a "for /f" loop with all files sorted by name and then renaming them to "._lenameX.jpg" with X as the order number, but I thought in a way to do it for other cases - if in future a similar problem appears, someone can modify some commands...

Comment: you can use "delims=" instead of "delims=¯" (I forgot that :D). also you can use for /f intead of for /f "delims=" because it does what I want in that case...

Answer (score 3):

If they are all in the same folder, you could select them all with `Control` + `A` and then hit `F2` to rename one of them. All subsequent files will be named file(2), file(3), etc

Answer (score 3):

Try Powershell (preinstalled in Windows 7):

```
Get-Childitem /path/to/your/files | foreach-object { move-item $_ $("._" + $_.name) }
```

(tested it in my download-dir.)

**Edit**: Siim K's code will append an additional ".jpg" to every "._filename.jpg".
Remove that last ".jpg" in Siim K's code and you have a short, elegant code to rename your files.

Comment: thanks, updated. Re-used code from a similar rename command which required the extension manipulation and didn't notice.

Answer (score 3):

[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/) has a really nice multi-renaming tool.

Answer (score 0):

I've always found [Flash Renamer](http://www.rlvision.com/flashren/about.asp) to be a good tool for renaming files in batches.

It has trial and full versions ($20) and can rename files based on meta data - very useful for renaming MP3 files which I what I use it for mostly.

Answer (score 0):

If your looking for a user friendly way of renaming in bulk you could try the free tool [Ant Renamer](http://www.antp.be/software/renamer), there's a huge list of actions you can take and it also gives a handy preview before you do any renaming. I use it a lot when messing with my music, photo or video librarys.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this freeware File Renamer program with great results.  Many different filters and options, plus it gives you the ability to test results.  A little outdated UI perhaps but works like a champ.

http://www.webxpace.com/software/freeware.shtml#FileRenamer